# Subtitles in ffmpeg/libavfilter

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have a C program to read video/audio with libav/ffmpeg libraries and decode it.

I am playing with some filters and most work just fine. I can draw text, overlay logos, flip and invert video colours. However, I am having big issues overlaying subtitles.

My filter is very simple.

```
const char *vfilter_descr = "[in]subtitles=subs.srt[out]";
```

On the console I get this:

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe76c703240] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 2.4.0 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe76c703240] Using font provider coretext
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe76c703240] fontselect: (Arial, 400, 0) -> /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf, -1, ArialMT
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe76c703240] fontselect: (Arial, 400, 100) -> /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial Italic.ttf, -1, Arial-ItalicMT
```

...which somewhat confirms that subtitles are loading, though I am not sure why there are two fonts being loaded?

However, they are not showing at all - almost as if they never loaded. I tried several different files, including ASS ones but no luck.

ffmpeg version is the latest one.

```
$ ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I never did manage to get it working. In the end, I used a separate function to read the subtitles from stream and overlay them over the video outside of ffmpeg filter.